# How does this recursive function outputs the characters in reverse order?

Tags: c, recursion

I know that the recursion step should simplify the expression but in this case I can't see how it does it. Shouldn't it increment the "&sPtr[1]" by using "&sPtr[i++]" and doing the proper modifications until it gets to the base case?

```
// recursively outputs characters in string in reverse order
 void reverse( const char * const sPtr )
 {
    // if end of the string
    if ( '\0' == sPtr[ 0 ] ) { // base case
       return;
    } // end if
    else { // if not end of the string
      reverse(&sPtr[1]);// recursion step
      putchar( sPtr[ 0 ] ); // use putchar to display character

    } // end else
 } // end function reverse
```

Comment: What is your question? Question's heading and body asks two separate things.

Comment: `&sPtr[1]` is the same as `sPtr+1` so it does increment the pointer to point to the next letter.

Comment: You can't do `&sPtr[i++]` because there's no variable `i`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that the putchar call is after the reverse call. Thus the reverse function will call itself, until it hits the null terminator and then the putchar calls will be called, in reverse order.

Call stack in order:

```
reverse("word")
 reverse("ord")
  reverse("rd")
   reverse("d")
    reverse("")
   putchar('d')
  putchar('r')
 putchar('o')
putchar('w')
```

---

Every time the code passes the string, it doesn't really pass the entire string, but only a pointer to it. So: `reverse( &sPtr[1] )` is the same as `reverse( sPtr+1 )`, the code is simply passing a pointer to the string starting at the next character.

Comment: How does the "reverse( &sPtr[ 1 ] )" moves to the next character. That's the main thing I just can't understand. To me that's just calling the address to the 2nd element.

Comment: @Alexandru When you make the recursive call, the 1st element is the 2nd element from the caller, so now `&sPtr[1]` is the 3rd element of the original string.

Comment: @Alexandru And each time you recurse, it goes to the next character of the original string, until you get to the end.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it!